# Should I use Objects.equals() on each element rather than Arrays.equals() when the array is composed of fields in my class?

Tags: java, equals

I'm writing a tuple utility, and so that I have the type safety of generics, I have a `TupleN` classes where N is the number of elements (and thus type parameters) it has, all of which inherit from an abstract class `Tuple`. Here's (a shortened version of) my `Tuple` class, as well as the `Tuple2` class (all the other `TupleN` classes follow the same pattern).

Tuple.java

```
public abstract class Tuple {

  public abstract int arity();

  public abstract Object get(int index);

  public Object[] toArray() {
    ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int arity = arity();
    for (int i = 0; i < arity; i++) list.add(get(i));
    return list.toArray();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o instanceof Tuple && Arrays.equals(toArray(), ((Tuple) o).toArray());
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Arrays.hashCode(toArray());
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.format("(%s)", String.join(", ", toArray().stream().map(t -> Objects.toString(t)).toList()));
  }

}
```

Tuple2.java

```
public class Tuple2<T0, T1> extends Tuple {

  public final T0 t0;
  public final T1 t1;

  public Tuple2(T0 t0, T1 t1) {
    this.t0 = t0;
    this.t1 = t1;
  }

  @Override
  public int arity() {
    return 2;
  }

  @Override
  public Object get(int index) {
    switch (index) {
      case 0: return t0;
      case 1: return t1;
      default: throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Object[] toArray() {
    return new Object[] {t0, t1};
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Tuple2) {
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      Tuple2<T0, T1> other = (Tuple2<T0, T1>) o;
      return Objects.equals(t0, other.t0) && Objects.equals(t1, other.t1);
    }
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.format("(%s, %s)", t0, t1);
  }

}
```

I was going to override both `equals` and `hashCode` in my `TupleN` classes for efficiency's sake, but I realized that my implementation of hashCode would be `return Objects.hashCode(t0, t1);`, which (from the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash(java.lang.Object...))) is the same as `return Arrays.hashCode(new Object[] {t0, t1});`, which (what with my overrided `toArray` method) is exactly what the default implementation does. After that, I realized that my override of `equals` is pretty much just the default implementation of `equals`, except where `Arrays.equals` had been "unfolded." My question is this: is that "unfold" sufficiently more efficient for it to be worth it to write out the override (which isn't too long for a `Tuple2`, but when it comes to a `Tuple7`, that sounds like a lot of boilerplate code), or would it be okay to just use the default implementation?

**EDIT:**

While I'm at it, I may as well ask the same about `toString`, though I imagine the default implementation of that takes more effort (what with streams and such).

Comment: You could greatly simplify your code by letting `Tuple` inherit from `AbstractList<Object>`. You only have to implement two methods, `get` (which you already have) and `size` (which is the same as `arity()`), and will get `equals`, `hashCode`, `toArray`, etc. for free. `equals` and `hashCode` will even work without creating an intermediate array. And `toString()` could get simplified to `String.format("(%s)", String.join(", ", this))`

Comment: `AbstractList` has lots of methods (i.e. `add`) that don't apply to tuples, and I try to avoid throwing excessive amounts of `UnsupportedOperationException`s, besides the fact that the `AbstractList` implelentation of `equals` is no more efficient than my `Tuple`'s implementation, and since I was asking this for the sake of performance, this doesn't help.

Comment: As said, `AbstractList`’s implementation *does* differ, as it doesn’t need a temporary copy, but I see your point regarding all these unwanted methods.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `Arrays.equals()` is enough for this. You do not need to check each one yourself.

The way I see it, you aren't reusing a lot of your things in your abstract class. You should be able to keep your own array (`Object[]`) and let your abstract class do most of the work.

```
public abstract class Tuple {
    private final Object[] data;

    protected Tuple(Object... data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    protected final Object[] getArray() { return data; }
    public final Object[] toArray() { return Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length); }

    public Object get(int index) {
        return data[index]; // You need to do your boundary checks
    }

    // Same hashcode and equals methods
}

public class Tuple2<T0, T1> extends Tuple {
    public final T0 t0;
    public final T1 t1;

    public Tuple2(T0 t0, T1 t1) {
         super(t0, t1);
         this.t0 = t0;
         this.t1 = t1;
    }
}
```

Comment: The point of the fields is so that you can easily get the value 0 as a `T0`, rather than just an object. So if I know I have a `Tuple2<String, Integer>` I can get the string with `String s = tuple.t0;` rather than `String s = (String) tuple.get(0);`. It's much more convenient and type safe.

Comment: @Anonymous I forgot your `t0` and `t1` fields are `public`. Then all you really need to add those fields back and assign them in constructor. Keeping your own array is still easier because all your checks in `equals()` and `hashcode()` would be easier and faster.

Answer (score 1):

`Objects.hashCode` calls `Arrays.hashCode`, but its use as *varargs* method duplicates the array creation code at the caller’s side, so the outcome might be even worse than your base class’ method. There might be optimizations on the JVM side, but that’s pure speculation and it would be pointless to create more code without knowing the actual implication to the performance.

I think, it’s worth to go the route of implementing an `equals` and `hashCode` method by hand here, if you do it only once for the base class without the need to create specializations in the subclasses, as all you need for a copy-free implementation is already there, namely `arity()` and `get(int)`. The implementation basically does the same as `AbstractList`, which you do not want to extend/inherit for the sake of a clean API (without unsupported methods).

A `toString()` method based on the Stream API should be sufficient for most purposes, though, even here there is no need to create an array first, not to speak of collecting into a `List`, just to call `String.join`, when you can collect into a string of the right format in the first place:

```
public abstract class Tuple {
    public abstract int arity();
    public abstract Object get(int index);

    public Stream<Object> elements() {
        return IntStream.range(0, arity()).mapToObj(this::get);
    }

    public Object[] toArray() {
        return elements().toArray();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return elements().map(Objects::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "(", ")"));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(o == this) return true;
        if(!(o instanceof Tuple)) return false;
        Tuple t = (Tuple)o;
        int n = t.arity();
        if(n != arity()) return false;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) if(!Objects.equals(get(i), t.get(i))) return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 1;
        for(int i = 0, n = arity(); i < n; i++)
            result = 31 * result + Objects.hashCode(get(i));
        return result;
    }
}
```

The effort spend in the base class methods pays off at the subclasses which do not need to provide optimized versions

```
public final class Tuple2<T0, T1> extends Tuple {
    public final T0 t0;
    public final T1 t1;

    public Tuple2(T0 t0, T1 t1) {
      this.t0 = t0;
      this.t1 = t1;
    }

    @Override
    public int arity() {
      return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(int index) {
        // starting with Java 9, you may consider Objects.checkIndex(index, arity());
        if((index|1) != 1) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
        return index == 0? t0: t1;
    }
}
```

```
public final class Tuple3<T0, T1, T2> extends Tuple {
    public final T0 t0;
    public final T1 t1;
    public final T2 t2;

    public Tuple3(T0 t0, T1 t1, T2 t2) {
      this.t0 = t0;
      this.t1 = t1;
      this.t2 = t2;
    }

    @Override
    public int arity() {
      return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(int index) {
        switch(index) {
            case 0: return t0;
            case 1: return t1;
            case 2: return t2;
            default: throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
        }
    }
}
```

```
etc
```

Beyond that, only provide overriding methods if a profiling tool revealed that there truly is a bottleneck at a certain place and also proves that the specialized implementation truly has a performance benefit over the general code.

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.equals()` will call your `equals()` method, and do the loop for you.

Ditto `toString()`. In this case as long as you're happy with the default output format of `Arrays.toString()` there is no need to look further.